# Convert newline to something else in variable using substitute

Tags: vimscript, functions, line-breaks

Inside of a variable, a newline is encoded as `^@` which represents a null byte.

In the vim Ex *command line* it is possible to issue something like `substitute(var, '^@', '\\n', 'g')`, this produces `\n` instead which can be passed to e.g. bash cleanly.

However, putting this into a function inside my vimrc breaks horribly with a missing quote E115, so I have to escape it somehow, but I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out that `'\n'` can be used in `substitute()` to refer to the null byte which is used internally to represent an end of line. This solved my problem.